# Segmentation fault while creating local structures across multiple processes in MPI

Tags: c++, struct, segmentation-fault, distributed-computing, openmpi

I am very new to distributed parallelism coding.
I am trying to create local instances of a struct (CountMin Sketch) across multiple processes and then initialize and update these local sketches independently in the processes but I am getting a segmentation fault.

The structure is

```
  struct CM_type{
      long long count;
      int depth;
      int width;
      int ** counts;
      unsigned int *hasha, *hashb;
  };
```

and the initialization and update function is

```
  std::vector<CM_type> CM_Init(int width, int depth, int seed, std::vector<KmerPairs> 
         &all_kmers_from_procs1)
  {
      int j;
      prng_type * prng;
      prng=prng_Init(-abs(seed),2); 
      #pragma omp parallel shared (width, depth, prng) //private(j)
      {
          #pragma omp for
          for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) //size is the number of processes
          {
               std::vector<CM_type> cm_loc;
               cm_loc[i].depth=depth;
               cm_loc[i].width=width;
               cm_loc[i].count=0;
               cm_loc[i].counts=(int **)calloc(sizeof(int *),cm_loc[i].width);
               cm_loc[i].counts[0]=(int *)calloc(sizeof(int), cm_loc[i].depth*cm_loc[i].width);
               cm_loc[i].hasha=(unsigned int *)calloc(sizeof(unsigned int),cm_loc[i].depth);
               cm_loc[i].hashb=(unsigned int *)calloc(sizeof(unsigned int),cm_loc[i].depth);
               if (cm_loc[i].counts && cm_loc[i].hasha && cm_loc[i].hashb && cm_loc[i].counts[i])
               {
                  for (j=0;j<depth;j++)
                  {
                      cm_loc[i].hasha[j]=prng_int(prng) & MOD;
                      cm_loc[i].hashb[j]=prng_int(prng) & MOD;
                      // pick the hash functions
                      cm_loc[i].counts[j]=(int *) cm_loc[i].counts[0]+(j*cm_loc[i].width);
                  }
               }
               for (size_t it=0; it<all_kmers_from_procs1.size(); it++) 
               {
                    KmerPairs k_entry1; //KmerPairs is another structure which has two members
                    k_entry1.seq = all_kmers_from_procs1[it].seq;
                    k_entry1.k_count = all_kmers_from_procs1[it].k_count;
                    int loc = 0;
                   __sync_add_and_fetch(&cm_loc[i].count, all_kmers_from_procs1[it].k_count);
                   for(int b = 0; b < cm_loc[i].depth; b++)
                   {
                       
                       cm_loc[i].counts[b][hash31(cm_loc[i].hasha[b], cm_loc[i].hashb[b], 
                all_kmers_from_procs1[it].seq) %cm_loc[i].width]+= all_kmers_from_procs1[it].k_count; 
                       printf("\nthe CM count is %d %d and the count is %llu \n", 
                              cm_loc[i].counts[b][hash31(cm_loc[i].hasha[b], cm_loc[i].hashb[b], 
                       all_kmers_from_procs1[it].seq) %cm_loc[i].width], cm_loc[i].count);
                       
                   }
              
              }
        } 
       
  } 

}
```

Each of my process has another structure called KmerPairs which has 2 members (the kmer sequence and the a count showing how many times that particular kmer is present in that process). I want to create local count min sketches by hashing the kmer sequence (which I have converted to binary) and increase the count in the count min sketch by the count member of the kmer. But I am getting error of segmentation fault like this:

```
  CountMin Sketch Started 
  [compute-2-9-ib:29987:0] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 
   address (nil))
  [compute-2-9-ib:29949:0] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 
   address (nil))
  [compute-2-9-ib:29950:0] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 
   address (nil))
  [compute-2-9-ib:29951:0] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 
   address (nil))
  [compute-2-9-ib:29952:0] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 
   address (nil))
  [compute-2-9-ib:29953:0] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 
   address (nil))
  [compute-2-9-ib:29954:0] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 
   address (nil))
  [compute-2-9-ib:29955:0] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 
   address (nil))
  [compute-2-9-ib:29956:0] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 
   address (nil))
  [compute-2-9-ib:29960:0] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 
   address (nil))
  [compute-2-9-ib:29963:0] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 
   address (nil))
  [compute-2-9-ib:29965:0] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 
   address (nil))
  [compute-2-9-ib:29970:0] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 
   address (nil))
  [compute-2-9-ib:29973:0] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 
   address (nil))
  [compute-2-9-ib:29976:0] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 
   address (nil))
  [compute-2-9-ib:29979:0] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 
   address (nil))
  [compute-2-9-ib:29981:0] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 
   address (nil))
  [compute-2-9-ib:29983:0] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 
   address (nil))
  [compute-2-9-ib:29985:0] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 
   address (nil))
  [compute-2-9-ib:29948:0] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 
   address (nil))
```

That is 20 segmentation faults for my 20 processes. Any guidance will be appreciated. I am happy to provide any more information. Thank you.

Comment: presumably due to `counts` only being valid in the process that called calloc?

Comment: The assignment to `cm_loc[i].counts[i]` is not how you initialize an array of pointers.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I changed that line to cm_loc[i].counts[0] instead of cm_loc[i].counts[i]. Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I thought the outermost for loop which is going from 0 to size (i.e. the process size) will help me to create the instances for all the processes separately.

Comment: There is MPI in the title and OpenMPI in your tags, but it doesn't seem you are using MPI any way (distributed parallelism). You are using OpenMP instead (shared-memory parallelism / thread). Is that right?

Comment: This: `std::vector<CM_type> cm_loc; cm_loc[i].depth=depth;` is very wrong. Th `cm_loc` vector is empty. Accessing any its elements by `cm_loc[i]` is undefined behavior. Also, your function does not return — again, undefined behavior. Shouldn't you have a single `cm_loc` declared and resized before entering the parallel region, use it inside, and return it at the end? Moreover, is use of `prng` thread-safe?

Comment: @DanielLangr I am having multiple processes but for now each process has just a single thread. I tried to define a single cm_loc outside the parallel region but that does not work either. My aim is that each process will have a local countmin sketch (cm_loc) which will hash the kmers inside that process only and then finally I will do a MPI_Allreduce() so that all processes can have a global view. That means each process will have a separate cm_loc

Comment: @DanielLangr I tried to return the cm_loc when I had initially defined it outside the omp parallel loop but that was giving me error since I want each process to have its separate cm_loc (i.e a local count min sketch data structure) and due to omp parallel region I could not give any return statements.